# recognize palindromic sequences and count them on a given number

Tags: sql, numbers, integer

I have an integer input like this 1213121

I would like to count how many palindromic sequences are there (the ouput must be 5 palindromic sequences)

Because the first palindromic sequence is 121.

The second is 1213121.

The third is 21312.

The fourth is 131.

The fifth is 121.

I tried to search on google but everything I found is spliting numbers or recognizing a palindromic number.

Could you help please?

Thanks for your time+

Comment: Would the 3rd be 21312 ? Also, which Sql RDBMS

Comment: Please explain how this is related to SQL.  If the data is in a database, please show the table layout and your expected results.

Comment: You're right Stuart.

Comment: Gordon, the exercise is for writting a sentence in sql script.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't specify your DBMS so here's a TSQL solution that at least shows you a simple method for what you need to do.

```
DECLARE @input VARCHAR(25) = '1213121';

WITH CTE_nums --just a list of numbers from 1 to the length of the input which is 7 in this case
AS
(
    SELECT 1 AS pos
    UNION ALL
    SELECT pos + 1
    FROM CTE_nums
    WHERE pos < LEN(@input)
)

SELECT  SUBSTRING(@input,A.pos,B.pos - A.pos + 1) AS palindrome_seq
FROM CTE_nums A
CROSS JOIN CTE_nums B --cross join to find every possible combination of those numbers
WHERE A.pos <= B.pos - 2 --only choose strings that are at least 2 characters long(not sure if you want it to be 2 or 3)
AND SUBSTRING(@input,A.pos,B.pos - A.pos + 1) = REVERSE(SUBSTRING(@input,A.pos,B.pos - A.pos + 1)) --check if that substring is the same reversed substring
```

Results:

```
palindrome_seq
-------------------------
121
1213121
21312
131
121
```